# How to combine in & if statements python

Tags: python, if-statement, printing, function

Im learning python2.7 and i cant seem to figure out how to check for a specific word in a string using the in & if statements for example.

```
v="this is test string"
def i():
    if "test" in v == True:
        return "its there"
print i
```

whenever i run this it just returns the location of i rather than printing "its there" or giving me an error and i just cant figure out what im doing wrong, i feel like im missing something really simple, ive tried switching out the return statement with a print but no difference.

Comment: also, saying "if x is True" is the same as just "if x".

Comment: @thg435 Technically they're quite different, but there's never a good reason to exploit the difference and you almost always want the latter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually have to call the function:

```
print i()
```

This executes the logic in the `i` function.

Comment: That's not necessary, functions can read globals just fine. Any time you call a module-level function or access anything from an imported module you do the exact same thing.

Comment: @delnan You're right, but isn't a function that can read many different variables that you pass it better? :)

Comment: @ecline6 No it isn't. It can already read them and when you're not planning on making the thing variable, the extra parameter is just pointless baggage.

Comment: Care to comment on the -1?

Comment: Also, I would encourage the OP to define the function as requiring `v` as an argument. This way it can be reused and is safer than using the global `v`.

Comment: Ah yes, I knew I forget something, sorry =/ I think it's very unfortunate and confusing that the answer now reads "[correct answer] -> [nonsense] -> nevermind, the last one's wrong". You should simply remove the latter two thirds, you had it right from the beginning. Edit: I strongly disagree that a parameter is better. It has absolutely nothing, and a read-only global has *no* downside (it's less flexible, but we're not building a framework here). Let's not overdo it. OP will run into parameters soon enough. And what's that about "safer"? Cut the FUD please!

Comment: That's all fine and well, but for readers encountering this thread as of right now, your answer is confusing: It is self-contradictory and most of the text is wrong/misleading. There's a log of previous edits for the historians. Editing wrong things out is perfectly fine, and is more helpful for those trying to learn from the answers IMHO.

Comment: I thank everyone for their answers and im sorry i caused somewhat of an argument :P, but everyone was helpful in one way or another :) I also changed accepted answer to this one if that makes everyone feel a little bit better.

Comment: We're all stubborn sometimes do to our egos. Here's an example: I also have a tendency to react negatively when somebody calls something 100% wrong until it's just what they want.  ; )

Answer (score 1):

Also you need to add a parameter to your function.  Let's call it 'v', and you don't need to compare to 'True'.  Try changing your code to this:

```
v="this is test string"
def i(v):
   if "test" in v:
      return "its there"
print i(v)
```

Comment: That's not necessary, functions can read globals just fine. Any time you call a module-level function or access anything from an imported module you do the exact same thing.

Comment: You're welcome.  Please checkmark an answer if your question is answered. Thanks!

Comment: Your answer is wrong. You missed the issue completely and only incidentally fixed the error OP was seeing, without addressing it.

Answer (score 0):

You should call the function using parenthesis:

```
print i()
```

Answer (score -1):

```
`if "test" in v:
    return True`
```

or

```
`if v.find('test') != -1:
    return True`
```